# Agregar evento con addEventListener a cada elemento de una matriz

Tags: javascript

Tengo que crear un `eventListener` para cada uno de los elementos de un arreglo:

```
    circulo[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    cantidadDeSlides = 0;
    detenerContador();
    reaunudarContador();
    slider(true);
    })

    circulo[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
    cantidadDeSlides = 1;
    detenerContador();
    reaunudarContador();
    slider(true);
    })

    circulo[2].addEventListener('click', function(){
    cantidadDeSlides = 2;
    detenerContador();
    reaunudarContador();
    slider(true);
    })
```

Si lo inicio de esta manera funciona todo correctamente, pero si lo quiero iniciar con un bucle `for` para recorrer todos los índices del arreglo no funciona (o por lo menos no de la manera en la que lo hago).

Dejo como estoy haciendo el bucle:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < circulo.length; i++){
    circulo[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    cantidadDeSlides = i;
    detenerContador();
    reaunudarContador();
    slider(true);
    })
```

Dejo mi HTML para que puedan ver el código completo, también puedo dar el archivo javascript y CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
         user-scalable=no, minium-scale=1.0, maxium-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class = "container" id = "container">
        <img class = "img" id="imagen1" src="img/0309cb3d-deco- 
        tortas_l_es_thumb.png" alt="R6">
        <img class = "img" id="imagen2" src="img/f0f7a6e1-torta-oreo-y- 
        ddl_l_thumb.jpg" alt="Rainbow Six Siege">
        <img class = "img" id="imagen3" 
        src="img/torta_Wk8PuOpz1Jl6D3KARHjErity4YwfVm.jpg" alt="Ovni">
        
        <div class="container_div" id = "container_div">
            <div class = "boton1" id = "button1"></div>
            <div class = "boton2" id = "button2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circulos">
            <div class="circulo"></div>
            <div class="circulo"></div>
            <div class="circulo"></div>
        </div>

    <script src="imagenesMoviles.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Agregarías tu html por favor?

Comment: @BetaM Ahi lo deje

Comment: ¿qué es círculo en tu js?

Comment: @BetaM Es una variable de tipo array: var circulo = document.getElementsByClassName('circulo');

Comment: Tu código es funcional (*lo acabo de probar en local*), deberías explicarnos un poco mas, dar mas detalles del comportamiento esperado

Comment: como armaste el array???

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que los objetos en `circulo` son referencias a elementos HTML, la siguiente estructura debería servir para agregar los listeners del evento click de manera dinámica para cada elemento:

```javascript
const circles = [
  document.createElement('span'),
  document.createElement('span'),
  document.createElement('span'),
  document.createElement('span'),
]

let counter = 0

for (const circle of circles) {
  circle.id = `circle-${counter++}`
  circle.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.isTrusted) { // Valida que el evento es desencadenado por una acción manual del cliente
      // Inserta funciones o acciones específicas
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es con lo que en Javascript se llama clausuras.

En tu ciclo:

```
for(var i = 0; i < circulo.length; i++){
  circulo[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    cantidadDeSlides = i;
    detenerContador();
    reaunudarContador();
    slider(true);
  })
}
```

dentro del `addEventListener` lo que ocurre es a que cantidadDeSlider se asigna el valor e la variable i en el momento que se presiona el click (en ese momento i va a tener el valor `circulo.length`) por eso no funciona.

Lo que necesitas es que `cantidadDeSlides` tenga el valor de i en el momento en que se ejecuta el ciclo. Para eso tienes que usar un truco, invocar a una función y pasar el valor de `i` como parámetro. Te lo muestro de dos maneras para que veas qué se quiere hacer (primero) y como abreviarlo (después):

```
function devolverManejadorParaCirculo(valor_i){
  return function(){
    cantidadDeSlides = valor_i;
    detenerContador();
    reaunudarContador();
    slider(true);
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < circulo.length; i++){
  circulo[i].addEventListener('click', devolverManejadorParaCirculo(i));
}
```

En el ejemplo de arriba ves cómo hay una función que devuelve un manejador, esa función también hace referencia a una variable, pero esa variable al estar dentro de la función (la variable `valor_i` va a tener un valor distintos cada vez, porque la función `devolverManejadorParaCirculo` que devuelve la función manejadora se la invoca una vez por cada elemento con un valor de `i` distinto cada vez.

Eso se puede escribir de forma abreviada así:

```
for(var i = 0; i < circulo.length; i++){
  circulo[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i){
    return function(){
      cantidadDeSlides = i;
      detenerContador();
      reaunudarContador();
      slider(true);
    };
  })(i)
}
```

En ese segundo ejemplo transformé la función `devolverManejadorParaCirculo` en una función anónima que está incluida en el lugar donde se va a usar (la primer `function`) que devuelve el manejador (segundo `function`), lo importante acá es que la primer `function` está encerrada entre paréntesis y se le pasa a `i` como parámetro para que el `i` que está dentro sea una copia de `i` en el momento de correr el ciclo. Lo de arriba y lo de abajo es lo mismo desde el punto de vista de lo que es, lo que se corre y las variables. La diferencia en lo de abajo es que es una escritura compacta y abreviada.

Es interesante aprender esto de las clausuras (que sirve para esto, array de elementos y tantas otras cosas).